# Playerctl/dbus not working with Spotify

Tags: d-bus, music-player

I need a way to play/pause Spotify from the command line, but the dbus method and playerctl both say 'connection refused'. How can I fix/troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2):

Now, in 2018, playerctl is working:

```
playerctl -p spotify play-pause
```

By using `playerctl --help`, you can see all available options. However, the `position` and `volume` options do not working with Spotify, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know the following might not answer your question, and probably you have tried the following dbus commands. But I put that here anyway for anyone else interested.

I am using ubuntu gnome & I personally created actions in the .desktop file of spotify to access next/prev etc

[image]

here is what it looks like, maybe it can help

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Spotify
GenericName=Music Player
Comment=Spotify streaming music client
Icon=spotify-client
Exec=spotify %U
TryExec=spotify
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Audio;Music;Player;AudioVideo;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/spotify;

Actions=PlayPause;Next;Previous;Stop

[Desktop Action PlayPause]
Name=Play-Pause
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause

[Desktop Action Next]
Name=Next
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next

[Desktop Action Previous]
Name=Previous
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous

[Desktop Action Stop]
Name=Stop
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Stop
```